# Execute a JFrame program

Tags: java, swing, execute

how to execute this program?

```
// Resolve class BorderLayout
import java.awt.*;
// Resolve class JFrame and JButton
import javax.swing.*;
// Definition of class FrameWithBorderLayout

public class FrameWithBorderLayout extends JFrame {// Attribute

    private JButton buttonEast; // The east button
    private JButton buttonSouth; // The south button
    private JButton buttonWest; // The west button
    private JButton buttonNorth; // The north button
    private JButton buttonCenter; // The center button
    // Constructor

    public FrameWithBorderLayout() {
        // Call super class constructor with a title
        super("Frame With Multiple Buttons");
        // Create JButton objects
        buttonEast = new JButton("East");
        buttonSouth = new JButton("South");
        buttonWest = new JButton("West");
        buttonNorth = new JButton("North");
        buttonCenter = new JButton("Center");
        // Add the JButton objects
        add(buttonEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(buttonSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(buttonWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(buttonNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Set when the close button is clicked, the application exits
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Reorganize the embedded components
        pack();
    }
}
```

---------------------------------current source-------------------------------------

```
// Resolve class BorderLayout
import java.awt.*;
// Resolve class JFrame and JButton
import javax.swing.*;
// Definition of class FrameWithBorderLayout
public class test extends JFrame {

// Attribute
    private JButton buttonEast; // The east button
    private JButton buttonSouth; // The south button
    private JButton buttonWest; // The west button
    private JButton buttonNorth; // The north button
    private JButton buttonCenter; // The center button
// Constructor
    public test() {
    // Call super class constructor with a title
        super("Frame With Multiple Buttons");
        // Create JButton objects
        buttonEast = new JButton("East");
        buttonSouth = new JButton("South");
        buttonWest = new JButton("West");
        buttonNorth = new JButton("North");
        buttonCenter = new JButton("Center");
        // Add the JButton objects
        add(buttonEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(buttonSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(buttonWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(buttonNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Set when the close button is clicked, the application exits
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Reorganize the embedded components
        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                   FrameWithBorderLayout frame = new FrameWithBorderLayout();
                   frame.setVisible(true);
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every Java program starts from a **main** method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
               FrameWithBorderLayout frame = new FrameWithBorderLayout();
               frame.setVisible(true);
          }
    });
}
```

Add this to your frame class.

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - <anonymous test$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in java.lang.Runnable
 at test.main(test.java:35)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: @hkinterview - Look at my latest answer:)

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol: class FrameWithBorderLayout
 at test$1.run(test.java:37)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Where have you put the main method?

Comment: there is red border under FrameWithBorderLayout in my netbean

Comment: You have declared your class as `test`. It should be declared as `FrameWithBorderLayout`.

Comment: @Petar, why do you an invokeLater in the main() method? I see that often lately but don't get why people are doing this.

Comment: @Angel - because all access to Swing components _must_ happen on the EDT and which is not the thread which starts the app, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: @Kleopatra That is not correct, creating a JFrame is not the same as accessing it or accessing other Swing components. I have hundrets of programs that simply instanciate their main frame in the main method and thats it. invokeLater is only needed to react on Actions etc. Also, that example aboive creates 3 threads, the EDT, the main thread, and the runable one. The work is only shifted from the main thread to the runnable, the EDT is not touched at all.

Comment: you did read the article, did you? In the ol' days it was considered safe to do frame creation and configuration on the initial thread, and most of the time that's safe enough. But evaluation (by core Swing team, not me - so is you think it's wrong, contact them :) shifted to do _every access to any Swing component_ (how would be initial access different from later access?) on the EDT. That't what the invoke guarantees: the runnable is executed on the EDT

Answer (score 0):

```
FrameWithBorderLayout frameTest = new FrameWithBorderLayout();
frameTest.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: there is red border under FrameWithBorderLayout in my netbeans